# Tabbed browsing with internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, tabbed-browsing

On my windows 7 x64 box, IE8/9 don't work. I can use the one default tab all i wish, but as soon as I open a new tab using ctrl-T, or middle click on a link or however, the browser stops reponding. I can not close it anymore, neither can i switch tabs, or interact with the options etc.

I have tried resetting the settings, and running the browser with the -extoff switch, but to no avail. This behaviour is identical across the 64 bit and the 32 bit version. Can you direct me to a suitable remedy?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the troubleshooting steps outlined in [this Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926449)?

Comment: Yes I have.No gains.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to Fix ‘Open in New Tab/Window’ problem in IE8 ?](http://webtrickz.com/how-to-fix-open-in-new-tabwindow-problem-in-ie8/) :

> Download [this registry file](http://webtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/files/Fix_IE8Win7.reg) and
>   run it. Click ‘Yes’ when dialog box
>   appears to add it to Windows registry.

Another script to fix such problems is found in [Repair IE8 (IE7)](http://iefaq.info/index.php?action=artikel&;cat=42&id=133&artlang=en).

**EDIT**

You can also try going to Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced tab, and at the bottom click on Reset.

Please also have a look at the Event Viewer at the time that such a freeze occurred.

Comment: Nope, the reg file does nothing

Comment: Have you tried both fixes? And see my edit.

Comment: I have tried both fixes. I have also reset all settings as mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem has been solved using the event viewer. I observed that every time I tried closing the tab, the family safety service from windows live essentials threw an error. An uninstall to the family safety nailed the issue.
I shall award you the bounty, but request you to please include this information in an edit to your answer.